# Closed subgroup of a pro-p group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups, pro-p-groups

I want to prove the following proposition:

> **Proposition**. If $H$ is a closed subgroup of a pro-$p$ group $G$, then $H$ is pro-$p$

There is a result that maybe can be used in order to prove that.

> If $H$ is a closed subgroup of a profinite group $G$, then $H$ is the inverse limite of the open subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.

I prove this result using some lemmas (if it is relevant, I can write the full proof here). By the way, $\color{red}{\text{can this result be used to prove the proposition?}}$ I try some things, but I cannot do something relevant

Also, if no I think there is an easier way to do that. An open subgroup $U$ of $H$ is like $H \cap K$ where $K$ is an open subgroup of $G$. If $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, then
$$p^n = |G:HK||HK:K|$$
from where
$$|H:U| = |HK:K| = p^m.$$
Unfortunately, $HK$ does not have to be a subgroup of $G$ (it is a subgroup if $H$ or $K$ is normal) so that the index is undefined. But I suspect that this idea can be improved. For example, $\color{red}{\text{if $U$ is normal in $H$, then $K$ must be normal in $G$?}}$

Comment: If $U$ is normal in $H$ it need not follow that $K$ is normal in $G$ - if $H = \{1\}$, then any non-normal compact open subgroup $K$ of $G$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The simplest way to prove this, is to show that $G$ being pro-p is equivalent to $G$ being compact and totally disconnected, with $G/N$ a p-group whenever $N$ is a normal open subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $G= \varprojlim_i G_i$ with each $G_i$ a finite $p$-group; and let $p_i: G\to G_i$ denote the canonical projection.

Can you prove that if $H$ is closed in $G$, then $H\cong \varprojlim_i p_i(H)$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My idea was to show that $H \subset \varprojlim p_i(H)$ and $H \supset \varprojlim p_i(H)$, but I cannot show the second inclusion. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Right, so let $x\in \varprojlim_i p_i(H)$. Then for any $i$, there is $y_i \in H$ such that $p_i(x) = p_i(y_i)$, but that means $y_i\in x \ker(p_i)$. But the family of $x\ker(p_i)$'s forms a basis of neighbourhoods for $x$, so $x$ is in the closure of $H$, i.e. $H$

Comment: Nice! I got it.